# How to make performSelector:withObject:afterDelay work?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsobject

Here's the code:

```
-(void)setProjectID:(NSString *)newProject {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"projectID"];
    [projectID release];
    projectID = [newProject copy];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"projectID"];

    // Since we have an ID, now we need to load it
    NSInvocation *returnInvocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:
                                      [Detail instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:@selector(configureView:)]];
    [returnInvocation setTarget:self];
    [returnInvocation performSelector:@selector(displayAlert) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
    [returnInvocation setSelector:@selector(configureView:)];
    [returnInvocation retainArguments];

    fetch = [[WBWDocumentFetcher alloc] init];
    [fetch retrieveDocument:[NSURL wb_URLForTabType:PROJECT_DETAILS inProject:projectID] returnBy:returnInvocation];
}

-(void)displayAlert
{
    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                           initWithTitle:@"Connection Error" 
                           message:@"Error loading Data."
                           delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                           otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

The app is crashing saying NSInvalidArguementException.
-[NSInvocation displayAlert]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5842320
Please help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `withObject`, just use `PerformSelector:afterDelay:`

Also, you should call this on `self`, not `returnInvocation`

Comment: still crashing and also its giving warning NSInvocation may not respond too performSelectpr:afterDelay

Answer (score 1):

I guess code should be like :

```
NSInvocation *returnInvocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:
                                  [Detail instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:@selector(displayAlert)]];

[returnInvocation setTarget:self];
[returnInvocation setSelector:@selector(displayAlert)];
[returnInvocation invoke];
```

or simply:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(displayAlert) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[self performSelector:@selector(displayAlert) withObject: message afterDelay:0.5];
```

Try this..

Answer (score 0):

`- (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anArgument afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay`  is performed on the object that calls it.

So if you call it on `returnInvocation` you are going to get the unrecognized selector error because NSInvocation doesnt have a `displayAlert` method.

Use

`[self performSelector:@selector(displayAlert) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];`

As the self has the method.